# Объединить два запроса к БД в один

Tags: mysqli, php

Есть таблица messages, где находятся  сообщения юзеров. В табличке есть поле status - значение 0 - сообщение прочитано, 1 - не прочитано. У меня так - сначала выводится общее кол-во сообщений, плюс к этому - количество непрочитанных.
Запрос для всех сообщений:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM  messages WHERE from_id IN ('$target_id','$id') 
  AND to_id IN('$target_id','$id')";
echo $mysqli->query($query)->num_rows
```

Для сообщений со статусом 1 - то же самое,но с добавлением **WHERE status='1'**

Получается 2 запроса и работают они с одними и теми же записями. На 106% я уверен, что эти запросы можно объединить в один. Подскажите хотя бы идею. Какие команды используются для запросов такого рода?

Comment: всегда используйте bind, .... по вопросу... второй запрос же сужает кол-во выводимых данных, как это может быть объединено в один запрос ? если только вы не хотите `SELECT id,status ....`

Comment: @eicto, ну в этом случае я всегда делал 2 запроса. И был прав оказывается. По поводу bind, нужно ознакомиться. Спасибо за поддержку!

Comment: @eicto, что за bind? Для чего он нужен???

Comment: [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) нужен , чтобы не случилось mysqlInject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем выполнять запрос, если он не нужен? Вы же получаете только количество записей? Так и получайте сразу количество записей:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM messages
WHERE
    from_id IN ('$target_id','$id')
AND
    to_id IN('$target_id','$id')
```

Поле cnt содержит количество записей - скорость выполнение запроса на несколько порядков будет выше, чем описана у вас.

Если хотите в один - можно через UNION добавить таким же образом второй запрос. В результатах - первый элемент - всего, второй - прочитано.

Можно попытаться сразу все сделать (если status либо равен 0, либо 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt, sum(status) as cnt_unread
FROM messages
WHERE
    from_id IN ('$target_id','$id')
AND
    to_id IN('$target_id','$id')
```

Хотя не знаю как это на скорость будет влиять, может быть даже быстрее будет, чем в моем первом варианте. Надо смотреть на очень большом числе данных.

На очень большом - т.к. на малом это конечно будет быстрее, а на большом может заметно тормозить.

Comment: 1.Что быстрее - один запрос с UNION или два отдельных запроса?
2. COUNT(1) - что означает 1? Первое поле?

Comment: Видимо имелось ввиду COUNT(id) или COUNT(*).

Comment: А ну тогда да... А то я уже... Что такое значение length/values для типа int в БД? Это его математическая величина или длина строкового представления числа? Я не нашел таких данных

Comment: @istem,  Что такое значение length/values для типа int в БД? Это его математическая величина или длина строкового представления числа? По-моему я прописывал любое значение и все работало при этом.

Comment: Думаю вы имеете ввиду количество цифр. Например для int(11) значение варьируется от -2147483648 до 2147483647. Для int(11) unsigned от 0 и 4294967296.

Думаю вы имеете ввиду количество цифр. Например для int(11) значение варьируется от -2147483648 до 2147483647. Для int(11) unsigned от 0 и 4294967296.

Comment: @istem, только что экспортировал БД на хост. Теперь скрипт не может в нее войти. Скажите, а имя пользователя и пароль БД тоже экспортируются?

Comment: Параметром COUNT может быть любое выражение, хоть число ПИ (кстати с праздником), результат не изменится

Comment: @Deus,

1) один запрос будет быстрее,

2) имелось ввиду именно COUNT(1), а не COUNT(id). Че-то слышал, что это либо одинаково по скорости, либо COUNT(1) будет быстрее чем COUNT(*). Хотя COUNT(1) вроде как нельзя использовать на JOIN`ах.

Хотел ссылку найти где это читал, но сейчас времени нет.

COUNT(id) не стоит использовать, если вы хотите подсчитать общее число записей, а не количество непустых записей.

В общем если интересно почитайте про COUNT(1) vs COUNT(*) vs COUNT(field).

Comment: параметр * в count повлечет некоторые дополнительные затраты на компиляцию